# Multi Instance Queue Manager

Tags: ibm-mq

When we issue command `dspmq -x` on the active server the output is shown as below.

```
QMNAME(A)               STATUS(RUNNING)
    INSTANCE(A_SERVER NAME) MODE(ACTIVE)
QMNAME(B)               STATUS(RUNNING)
    INSTANCE(A_SERVER NAME) MODE(ACTIVE)
```

---

Output of `dspmq -x` on standby server

```
QMNAME(A)               STATUS(RUNNING)
    INSTANCE(A_SERVER NAME) MODE(ACTIVE)
    INSTANCE(B_SERVER NAME) MODE(Standby)
QMNAME(B)               STATUS(RUNNING)
    INSTANCE(SERVER NAME) MODE(ACTIVE)
    INSTANCE(B_SERVER NAME) MODE(Standby)
```

---

Why are the standby server/instance details not showing on the active server.

Comment: I reformatted your question with some code blocks around the fixed ASCII output of dspmq.  You can click edit to see how this is done for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I run the same command "dspmq -x" and the output is as below,
It shows both active/standy server details.

On Server 1:

QMNAME(QM1)                                             STATUS(Running as stan                                                                                                                                                             dby)

```
INSTANCE(server1) MODE(Active)

INSTANCE(server2) MODE(Standby)
```

QMNAME(QM2)                                             STATUS(Running)

```
INSTANCE(server2) MODE(Active)

INSTANCE(server1) MODE(Standby)
```

---

On Server 2:

QMNAME(QM1)                                             STATUS(Running)

```
INSTANCE(server1) MODE(Active)

INSTANCE(server2) MODE(Standby)
```

QMNAME(QM2)                                             STATUS(Running as standby)

```
INSTANCE(server2) MODE(Active)

INSTANCE(server1) MODE(Standby)
```

---